# How does a monkey head touch a cube

Tags: python, node-editor, geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

How does a monkey head touch a cube

Answer (score 6):

Add a *Store Named Attribute* in a simulation zone. I called it *status*. Store  a boolean with the value $1$ on it.

The selection, to which this attribute is applied, is driven by a mesh boolean between the cube and the monkey head.

We can determine, if the meshes intersect, by examining the point count of the resulting mesh. If it is larger than 0 they intersect. Thanks to auto-casting we can insert the point count of the boolean mesh directly into the selection input of the *Store Named Attribute* node.

Make sure to set the material and read the *status* attribute from the material nodes.

[image: Node Setup]
<sup>Left: Material Setup, Right: Geometry Node setup on the cube</sup>

You need to play the animation starting on the first frame or cache the simulation zone to properly see the attribute change.

Comment: Thank you very much